# Why does the subtraction symbol go away? $-(-x)= x$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$+(+x) = +x$

but why is $-(-x) = +x$???

What's the reason behind the rule, it's really basic and "obvious"
because a no turns a no to a yes

But I don't want to reason like that, lol. So how would you explain it?
Do I just say on a real number line $-x$ makes a turnaround and $-(-x)$ would turn it positive again?

Also if I say for example: $-x = 5$ then I do have $-(-x) = -5$
Is it correct? It wouldn't matter, right?

(Btw: I don't know if the tag "elementary-number-theory" is correct)

**The question is different to $(-x)*(-x)=x$

Comment: I don't think so because that question is too advanced for me.
Also I do talk about two minus symbols on one variable

Comment: I am sure some of the $40$ answers there are appropriate for your level. Note also $-(-x)=(-1)\cdot (-x)$

Comment: Also related [Proof that $-(-x) = x$ using just the field axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234405/proof-that-x-x-using-just-the-field-axioms), [Are $x \cdot 0 = 0$, $x \cdot 1 = x$, and $-(-x) = x$ axioms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375/are-x-cdot-0-0-x-cdot-1-x-and-x-x-axioms)

Comment: Yes, next time you find a similar "basic and obvious" thing you want to ask, do a search first. Odds are you're not the first to ask. Or even the 20th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better abstract-algebra proof, but I will here give somewhat simpler version.

Let $X$ be an additive inverse of $x$, that is $x + X = 0$. Note that equation $X = 0 - x = - x$ holds $\forall x, X \in \text{G}$ where $G$ is some group ($0$ is additive identity).

We can subtract $X$ from both sides: $x + X - X = 0 - X.$ Thus, $x = - (-x)$. In simpler terms, subtracting $- x$ is adding $x$.

There are plenty of geometric answers there so I will not 'steal' and write them here. I will just mention that semantic $+ (+ x) = +x$ holds because of *covention* (easier is to manipulate symbols like that). That pluses esentially aren't the same thing, they are different operations. Simillary for $- \ x \equiv 0 - x$ and $-x$ which is additive inverse. Because of that we have $- \ (-x) \neq -x$ or $- \ x$ for $x \neq 0$.

You will easly see that geometrical argument for $\pm a \cdot \pm b = \pm c$ (of course, signs can be in different order!) and also take for simplicity $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$, is built on convention that first $+$ is right (then first $-$ is left) and second $+$ is adding to the previous orientation (then second $-$ is subtracting from previous orientation  which is same as adding to inverse orientation of the previous one), third $+$ is position of resulting number, right from $0$, then we write $-$ if result is left from $0$.

Also see this:
$0 - 2 = 2', 0 - 1 = 1', 0 - 0 = 0.$ You see that results are increasing, so $0 - 1' = 1.$

Comment: Thanks! I have to sleep over it.

Answer (score 0):

If a car makes a U-turn twice, it will end up going in the original direction.

Comment: Is there really no other idea behind this? xD

Comment: When there are only two possible orientations, the mapping that maps each orientation to the other is [involutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)).